# Asp.net default theme css menu problem

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, menu

Net 2.0 default theme in VS 2010, which is blue header and white body, its menu is good, but when the page loads, menu first opens in a disturbing way, and then close in a proper position, this is css problem, if the page is heavy or takes some time, the menu gets disturbed, any body has idea, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks
Atif

Comment: Can you post an example of what you mean with 'open in a disturbing way' Is there Javascript involved?

Comment: No, there is no Java Script i think, forexample the menu is  Home About Us Contact us, it is in horizontal way, but then the page is getting load, its shown vertically, and when the page load completes, it gets ok and return to position, this is a css problem m sure

Comment: But when the page is not fully loaded, the menu is displayed vertically. When the loading is completed (page is fully loaded) the menu is displayed correctly?

Comment: yes absolutely this is what happens.

Comment: So based on that, I'd say that this is normal, because the browser is only able to display everything correctly once the full css file is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Work around for Menu control load asthetics on slow browsers: JTankers; 2011/06/17

Replace the  tag with:

```
  <body onload="document.getElementById('div_Menu').style.visibility='visible'">
```

Place the menu control in the following div:

```
  <div id='div_Menu' style='visibility: hidden'; >
    <asp:Menu ...
  </div>
```