# All css classes not loading in webpage

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, aspmenu-control

I have an application converted to VS 2010. The asp:menu's css classes are not loading completely. When i click on compatible view of browser, the css works fine.

Any idea on what can be the issue and how it can be fixed ?

Code for reference:

```
<div class="SetHeight">
            <asp:Menu ID="MasterMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4"
                Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="3" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="tab"
                StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="slctTab" CssClass="tabs" StaticSubMenuIndent="0px">
            </asp:Menu>
</div>

        .SetHeight
        {
            border-bottom: 1px solid red;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            clear: both;
        }

        table.tabs
        {
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
        }

        table.tab
        {
        }

        a.tab, a.tab:selected, a.tab:link, a.tab:active, a.tab:visited
        {
            background-color: Green;
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 650;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: White;
            padding: 2px 7px;
            display: block;
        }

        a.tab:hover
        {
            background-color: #009900;
        }

        a.slctTab, a.slctTab:hover, a.slctTab:link, a.slctTab:active, a.slctTab:visited
        {
            color: White;
            background-color: Blue text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Comment: Upgrading to VS 2010 shouldn't affect your code in any way, unless your settings force different styling or coding standards, or if you upgraded your .NET framework version.  Can you show your CSS and menu code?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here. Hope this solves your problem. In this we load the asp:menu inside a div and put the style visibility as visible [Asp.net default theme css menu problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893976/asp-net-default-theme-css-menu-problem)

Comment: @RMN try to replace the default css for asp:Menu with simply the id of the menu ie MasterMenu so write the new css for asp:Menu something like this #MasterMenu{ // your css porps}